# TortoiseGit: What's the difference between "Git Sync", "Fetch" and "Pull"?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I am moving from TortoiseSvn to TortoiseGit. But enountered some unexpected difficulties.

My working paradigm is as simple as:

1. Check out code
2. Change some code
3. Share with others for code review
4. Commit changes

Why bother to have the 3 `syntactically` similar commands below?

And `Pull` and `Fetch` even share the identical icon. What a user-friendly design!

[image]

Comment: I would recommend that you start reading a Git tutorial, because you should not proceed further until you know these basics.  I could give an answer, but there will still be many more questions you will have.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I am reading this (http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/). Hope it can un-puzzle me.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

These are three different commands:

1. Git `pull` is a git `fetch` followed by git `merge` - [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-are-the-differences-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)
2. Git `fetch` fetches info about remote repositories - [read here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)
3. Git `sync` does everything in one command meaning `pull` and `push` [read here](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-sync.html)

If you want to compare `git` and `svn` workflow then `git pull` is like `svn update`. There's no direct `svn` version of git `fetch`. Git `sync` is like `svn up` && `svn commit` in one command

Comment: I tried using Git Sync and it told me the command doesn't exist?

Comment: because there's no such command as `git sync` in git's CLI, it's just an option in TortoiseGit

Answer (score 4):

You can do a git fetch at any time to update your remote-tracking branches under refs/remotes//.

`git fetch` **operation never changes any of your own local branches** under refs/heads, and is safe to do without changing your working copy. I have even heard of people running git fetch periodically in a cron job in the background (although I wouldn't recommend doing this).

`git pull` **is what you would do to bring a local branch up-to-date with its remote** version, while also updating your other remote-tracking branches.